Restricting access to PHPMyAdmin on Apache to specific IP addresses
I am trying to restrict access to PHPMyAdmin running on an Apache server to specific IP addresses. I want to allow access only from two specific IP addresses while denying access from all others. Using ubuntu 22.04 LTS and phpmyadmin version 5.1.1deb5ubuntu1.
Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-04-10T17:45:18
I have tried the following Apache configuration:
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/:/usr/share/javascript/
    </IfModule>

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from xxxx.xxxx.100.100
    Allow from xxxx.xxxx.113.12
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>

However, this configuration does not seem to work as expected. Even after specifying the allowed IP addresses, access to PHPMyAdmin is still denied from all IP addresses. I have also tried removing the Deny from All line, which allows access from any IP address, but I want to restrict access to only the specified IP addresses.
How can I properly configure Apache to restrict access to PHPMyAdmin to only the specified IP addresses?

Which Apache version? In 2.4 and later, this should be done this way, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/auth.html#beyond

@CBroe Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server built: 2024-04-10T17:45:18
